# Android banner Ad layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, admob

My page has a footer containing navigation image buttons (back and forwards) defined as a `RelativeLayout`.

```
<!-- Footer aligned to bottom. This is for the menu -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_menu_bgd"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_btn_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/bottom_menu_home"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_btn_play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/bottom_menu_play"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to add a banner Ad just on the top of the footer.
I have tried to insert a LinearLayout (used the banner Ad) in the RelativeLayout but it showed the banner on the same position of the footer.

How can I move the banner Ad in order to be showed just on the top of footer ?

Comment: paste full layout xml code. so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your Banner **AdView** at end of RelativeLayout and make it above footer layout by adding `android:layout_above="@+id/footer"`  to **AdView**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom. This is for the menu -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_menu_bgd"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_btn_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/bottom_menu_home"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_btn_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/bottom_menu_play"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



    <!-- Add your Banner AdView here  -->

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"    
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply weights to all your layouts. 
Assign weight_sum = 10 to your parent layout. 
and then

```
layout_weight="8" ---to layout above footer,
layout_weight = "1" ---to footer
layout_weight = "1" ---to banner ad
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Demo code It will contain two button at bottom of screen and Adview above bottom images:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/action_bar_hover"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_btn_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_btn_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
            android:visibility="visible" />


    </RelativeLayout>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
        android:layout_above="@id/my_view"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I will test it this evening. But please, check my .xml code. In the footer RelativeLayout there is a background image. The banner must be above this background image as well